# maintaining query-oriented applications

Tags: sql, mysql, database, data-mining

I am currently doing some kind of reporting system.the figures, tables, graphs are all based on the result of queries. somehow i find that complex queries are not easy to maintain, especially when there are a lot of filtering. this makes the query very long and not easy to understand. And also, sometimes, queries with similar filters are executed, making a lot of redundant code, e.g. when i am going to select something between '2010-03-10' and '2010-03-15' and the location is 'US', customer group is "ZZ", i need to rewrite these conditions each time i make a query in this scope. does the dbms (in my case, mysql) support any "scope/context"  to make the coding more maintainable as well as the speed faster?

also, is there a industrial standard or best practice for designing such applications?
i guess what I am doing is called data mining, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Learn how to create views to eliminate redundant code from queries.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html
2. No, this isn't data mining, it's plain old reporting.  Sometimes called "decision support".  The bread and butter of information technology.  Ultimately, play old reporting is the reason we write software.  Someone needs information to make a decision and take action.

   Data mining is a little more specialized in that the relationships aren't easily defined yet.  Someone is trying to discover the relationships so they can then write a proper query to make use of the relationship they found.

Answer (score 0):

You won't make a very flexible reporting tool if you are hand coding the queries.  Every time a requirement changes you are up to your neck in fiddly code trying to satisfy it - that way lies madness.

Instead you should start thinking about a meta-layer above your query infrastructure and generating the sql in response to criteria expressed by the user.  You could present them with a set of choices from which you could generate your queries.  If you give a bit of thought to making those choices extensible you'll be well on your way down the path of the many, many BI and reporting products that already exist.

You might also want to start looking for infrastructure that does this already, such as [Crystal Reports](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/index.epx) (swallowed by Business Objects, swallowed by SAP) or Eclipse's [BIRT](http://eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/).  Depending on whether you are after a programming exercise or a solution to your users' reporting problems you might just want to grab an off the shelf product which has already had tens of thousands of man years of development, such as one of those above or even [Cognos](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/) (swallowed by IBM) or [Hyperion](http://www.oracle.com/hyperion/index.html) (swallowed by Oracle).

Best of luck.